# Why Amazon SNS service doesn't let me choose SMS subscription protocol?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sns

I'm trying to send some SMS using the SNS services from Amazon, I'm following the tutorial available at https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/sms_publish-to-topic.html however AWS won't let me choose the SMS as a valid protocol, it only appears the SQS choice:

[image]

I've already set up my phone number to SMS sandbox and was able to publish a SMS message directly, following the tutorial: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/sms_publish-to-phone.html#sms_publish_console

Anyone knows why this SMS protocol isn't available on AWS SNS service?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I've just found out that it was because I set my topic as FIFO instead of Standard...
If anyone runs on the same insane and silly mistake, please pay attention on that before going mad under google searching for this.

Comment: Same with email and email-JSON. The only protocol that shows up when FIFO is enabled is Amazon SQS.